# Search a string and write it in a new text file along with its next line by using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a code in Python for searching a string in a huge text file which will occur every 10-15 lines and copying its next line in another text file. I am a beginner in Python so  not sure what would be best to do this. I am trying by using the below script:

```
name = raw_input('Enter file:')
    with open(name) as f:
        with open("output.txt", "w") as f1:
            for line in f:
                if "IDENTIFIER" in line:
                    f1.write(line)
```

After this what I need in output file is the entire next line after this string is found.

something like line+1 which I suppose is not available in Python.

How can I jump to the next line and write that line in the output file after me text IDENTIFIER?

Comment: If the next line also contains this string, how should this be handled?

Comment: how big is the file?

Comment: Next line does not contain the same string... It is much like an identifier and its description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open("file_in.txt") as f:
   with open("file_out.txt","w") as f2:
        for line in f:
            if "my_test" in line:
                f2.write(line.rstrip("\n")+next(f)) # the next line :P
```

Comment: This is a better answer, for sure. +1 :-)

Comment: Or `f1.writelines(line+next(f,"") for line in f if "IDENTIFIER" in line)`

Comment: If 2 consecutive lines contain `"my_test"` the 3rd line won't be written to the output file.

Comment: @user81269 this is true ... however OP explicitly states(in the comments after I had written this answer) this will never occure

Comment: But can you suggest if we can have both these outputs on the same line?

Comment: Joran, I was looking for output of f2.write(line+next(f)) on the same line... Currently this result looks like :
IDENTIFIER1 
DESCrIPTION1

However I need it on same line 
IDENTIFIER1  DESCrIPTION1
Having a comma separator will also  work or a space will be okay too :)

Comment: I already fixed it :P see my recent edit ... I just take the newline out of line ...

Comment: Awesome Joran.. :) You are genius!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `flag` variable:

```
flag = False

name = raw_input('Enter file:')
with open(name) as f:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if flag:
                f1.write(line + '\n')
                flag = False  
            if "IDENTIFIER" in line:
                f1.write(line)
                flag = True
```

Comment: This works too.. but in an ideal case Identifier does not come consecutively.. However output I expect is having the identifier and its description on the same line.. Can this be done?